# Theme support for post-thumbnails stopped working after upgrading to Wordpress 5.7

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-gutenberg

I just upgraded to Wordpress 5.7 and I don't see the option to add a post thumbnail any more.

I checked my functions.php and everything is still fine:

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
```

I have tried all kind of stuff, but nothing that solves the problem, where it used to work perfectly before the upgrade.

I also tried:

```
function theme_setup(){
    /** post thumbnail **/
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
}
add_action('after_setup_theme','theme_setup');
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution:

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/theme-support-for-post-thumbnails-stopped-working-after-upgrading-to-wp-5-7/

It was because of an older version of jquery-ui.

Answer (score 0):

## Feb 2022

Make sure you have the `index.php` file exist.
See my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/71261080/5413283