# Featured image of Wordpress doesn't appear in Admin

Tags: php, wordpress, thumbnails

I configured functions.php with the code that enables Post Thumbnails on the theme, but it doesn't appear in wp-admin.

```
<?php
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
set_post_thumbnail_size( 1280, 720 );
```

When I create a post, the option to upload the featured image does not appear. So, I did the following procedures to try to understand what is going on.

1. I disabled all plugins
2. I changed the theme (and the featured image appears in wp-admin normally)
3. I removed all code from functions, leaving only the code above
4. I updated WordPress

I don't know what to do anymore, I researched a lot and I can't find a solution. Could anyone have mercy on my soul? Thanks!!!

Comment: Did you hook it to any of the wordpress hooks?

Answer (score 1):

## Feb 2022

### WordPress version 5.9.1

It's been 9 months and I hope OP  found the solution.
If anyone came to this post asking for the same question then try this.

Here's what the Official Theme Handbook says

> **index.php**
> The main template file. It is required in all themes.

#### Solution

Make sure your theme has an `index.php` file.
It doesn't matter it has content or is empty, but the **file has to exist.**

Thanks to @teshn for finding this.

Answer (score 0):

Anything that is declared inside the `function.php` file need to be hooked onto a action/filter.

```
<?php

/**
 * Registers theme support for a given feature.
 * 
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_theme_support/
 */
add_action( 'init', 'theme_support' );

if ( ! function_exists( 'theme_support' ) ) {

    function theme_support () {

        /**
         * This feature enables Post Thumbnails support for a theme. Note that you can optionally pass a second argument, $args, with an array of the Post Types for which you want to enable this feature.
         * 
         * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_theme_support/#post-thumbnails
         */
        add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );

    };

};
```

---

### Custom post type case

If you're talking about custom post type, when you register a new one via [`register_post_type()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/) you can specify a [`support`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/#parameters) argument array.

```
// ...
'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', ) // Default is an array containing 'title' and 'editor'.
```

| Argument | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `supports` | (`array`) Core feature(s) the post type supports. Serves as an alias for calling `add_post_type_support()` directly. Core features include '`title`', '`editor`', '`comments`', '`revisions`', '`trackbacks`', '`author`', '`excerpt`', '`page-attributes`', '`thumbnail`', '`custom-fields`', and '`post-formats`'. Additionally, the 'revisions' feature dictates whether the post type will store revisions, and the 'comments' feature dictates whether the comments count will show on the edit screen. A feature can also be specified as an array of arguments to provide additional information about supporting that feature. Example: `array( 'my_feature', array( 'field' => 'value' ) )`. Default is an array containing '`title`' and '`editor`'. |

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at the right place? Because that's nothing fancy.

Comment: Yes, I have done this several times, I do not understand why it isnt working.

Comment: Wait are you talking about a page/post ? or a custom post type ?

Comment: I've edited the answer just in case you're talking about CPTs.

Comment: No, I want it to work on the common post / page, without posttypes or customization, but the Featured Image does not appear in the editor. My theme is newly created, it has only what is necessary to work, so it shouldn't be a conflict, even if there are no plugins installed.

Answer (score 0):

You could hook it to `after_setup_theme` action hook. So, the code would be something like this:

```php
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'your_theme_features');

function your_theme_features()
{
  add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
  set_post_thumbnail_size( 1280, 720 );
};
```

"Copy/paste" the code in your `functions.php`. The "the featured image" section should show up for your posts. Also you should be able to use `set_post_thumbnail_size` function too.

Comment: What do you mean "didn't work"? Did you get any error? Did you see the "featured image"  on the backend?

Comment: The featured image selection block does not appear in the admin when I am going to publish a post or page. It shows no error.

Comment: Did you put the code into the `functions.php` of your active theme? Did you save it after "copy/paste"? It works fine on my end!

Comment: Yes, it's in functions.php on the theme. I've even copied the functions.php code from another theme, but it doesn't work here and I've been trying to find out the problem for 3 days.

Comment: Hmmm! That's interesting! Like i said, it works fine on my end and it should do the same on your end. The only thing i can think of at this point is your wordpress files. Make sure they're not corrupted. I'd download the new version of wordpress and give it a try. Also try to echo something from your `functions.php` to see whether you're working with the right `functions.php` file.

Comment: I've already tried these steps, including recreating the theme files. I will continue to edit the theme that sometime this part may work.